# Using $variable in Parenthesis in Tcl (proc)

Tags: tcl

A part of my code in tcl is:

```
proc Frame {columnLine} {
.
.
.
}
```

Now I want use $variable in parenthesis. For example:

```
set x 2.
set columnLine {$x 5. 10. 15.}
```

However, after running Tcl, I face an error! How I do solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tcl does not do substitutions on things inside `{`braces`}`. If you want substitutions, you've got to *either* put the overall word inside `"`double quotes`"`, or use the `subst` command:

```
set x 2.
set columnLine [subst {$x 5. 10. 15.}]
```

```
set x 2.
set columnLine "$x 5. 10. 15."
```

One advantage of using `subst` is that you can pick to just substitute variables and leave backslashes and `[`bracketed command calls`]` alone. This is sometimes very useful indeed.

```
set x 2.
set columnLine [subst -nobackslashes -nocommands {$x 5. 10. 15.}]
```